# How can I reduce the double-click speed below the slowest setting in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mouse-click, double-click

How can I reduce the double-click speed beyond the slowest setting available in Windows 7?

I am aware of this setting in the mouse property:

[image: Double click speed in Mouse Properties]

However I would like to further reduce the double-click speed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [TechNet - DoubleClickSpeed](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978662.aspx), the correlated registry key value is from **100-900** for the milliseconds.

> ### DoubleClickSpeed
>
> ```
> HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse
> ```
>
> > **Data type**: `REG_SZ`
> >
> > **Range**: `100–900 ( milliseconds, in decimal )`
> >
> > **Default value**: `500`
>
> **Description**
>
> Specifies the maximum time between mouse clicks that are interpreted
>   as a double-click. If the time between clicks exceeds the value of
>   this entry, the clicks are interpreted as single clicks.
>
> **Change method**
>
> To change the value of this entry, double-click Mouse in Control
>   Panel. Click the Buttons tab and use the Double-click speed slider.
>
> <sub>[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978662.aspx)</sub>

I tested by moving the `Mouse Properties` double-click speed all the way to the right to **Fast** and the correlated registry key value was `200`

[image]

I then tested by moving the `Mouse Properties` double-click speed all the way to the left to **Slow** and the correlated registry key value was `900`

[image]

I then set the correlated registry value to values higher and tested and then refreshed, etc. to confirm the higher value settings stuck.

It appears that setting this value to `5000` and then comparing the double-click speed is affected but I'm not sure how to measure to tell 100% for sure but this is simple enough for you to test to confirm if you want.

Based on all the information I could find on this inquiry with **Windows 7**, this is what I determined with my testing.

[image]